# Django: How to render form field by html_name

Tags: python, django, django-forms

How can I render specific form field if I know its `html_name`?

Lets say I have this form:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    approve = forms.BooleanField()
```

Then `form.fields['approve'].html_name == 'approve'`. I tried in my template.html:

```
{{ form.fields.approve }}
```

But I get `<django.forms.fields.BooleanField object at 0x2b2bf4503290>` text rendered instead of input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form.fields` holds the form.Field instances. You want the `BoundField` instances, which are accessible directly from the `form` instance using key access (in Python code) or dotted access (in template code). IOW:

in python:

```
form["approve"]
```

in templates :

```
{{ form.approve }}
```

Now note that it's **not** the `html_name` you have to use but the **field** name.